# Setting up SocketIO server on AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, socket.io

I've got a problem to run the server with socketIO module on AWS EC2 server. My current code:

```
const port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var server = require('http').Server();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
const socketioHandler = require(backPath + 'functions/socketioHandler');
socketioHandler.ioConnections(io);

server.listen(port, 'ec2-IP_XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com');
```

And the URI that I'm using to connect client to the server:

```
ec2-IP_XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080
```

It seams that for some reason the client cannot find the server.

Comment: Have you checked your Inbound and outbound rules ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: can some one please suggest which file must. have these connection details ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the issue regarding the Security Group.

Security Groups has an Inbound rule, which is actually related to Port block or which all port should be open for the outside world.

So you have to open port 8080 for outside world.

[image]

[image]

So just add port 8080 (through edit option) in your inbound rules

Comment: can you explain better how to do this, please? thanks!

Comment: @AriWaisberg is your issue is exact ?? what is being mentioned in the question